# Python setlocale with empty string (default locale) gives "unsupported locale setting"

Tags: python, locale

I’m getting the following error:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

The setup is a newly installed and updated Fedora 34 system with Python 3.9.6. The error occurs when running [Lutris](https://lutris.net/), and also when typing the commands into IDLE. Here is the exact backtrace from Lutris:

```
lutris:33:<module>:BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lutris", line 31, in <module>
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/locale.py", line 610, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lutris", line 33, in <module>
    sys.stderr.write("Unsupported locale setting. Fix your locales\n")
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Given that, according to the Python docs, “[An empty string specifies the user’s default settings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale),” I figured maybe my default locale (`en_AU.UTF-8`) wasn’t supported at some level of the stack. But the following all work fine:

```
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_AU', 'UTF-8')
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale.getdefaultlocale())
'en_AU.UTF-8'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_AU.UTF-8')
'en_AU.UTF-8'
```

And oddly, the error *doesn’t* happen when I run `python` in a terminal and type the commands there!

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_TIME=C.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_NAME=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_AU.UTF-8'
```

So I have no idea what locale Python *thinks* it’s setting when I run IDLE or Lutris from the desktop, but it’s evidently not the same one set when I use the terminal. How can I debug this error?

(Incidentally, running Lutris from the command line has been a successful workaround.)

Comment: A little late to the party, but you should check what language-related environment variables are set inside Lutris

Comment: @Cimbali Not sure how to go about getting the environment variables from Lutris (any suggestions?), but it’s easy enough to get them from IDLE and from Python. I’ll add what I found to the question itself.

Comment: @Cimbali …or alternatively I might dive a little deeper and find the answer thanks to your suggestion. Writing it up now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the environment variable `LC_TIME`. Apparently I have it set to `en_150.UTF-8` from the desktop, but to `C.UTF-8` from the terminal.

[Cimbali’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68962248/3623267#comment126928631_68962248) set me on the right track. I looked at the environment variables using `os.environ`, within both IDLE-started-from-the-desktop and Python-started-from-the-terminal.

The ones that appeared locale-related were `LANG`, `LANGUAGE`, and `LC_TIME`. The first two were the same between the two cases, but the last one differed.

And this made the error go away:

```
>>> os.environ['LC_TIME'] = 'C.UTF-8'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

Which just leaves me wondering, what the heck is `en_150`? Is it because I have my desktop set to 24-hour time rather than the default? (Also wondering whether a bug report/request for more descriptive error messages would be useful for Python.)

Comment: `en_150` seems to be [“English (Europe)”](https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/en-150/index.html), the same as en_GB but with a decimal separator of `,` instead of `.` and no default currency. That website doesn’t report on clock formats but maybe it also has a 24h clock by default. Also discussed [on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1519501). However it seems python does not support a lot of the (fancier? newer?) language codes. I ran into this as it doesn’t support traditional/simplified Chinese (and uses Taiwan/China country codes instead).